# How should I build autolayout constraints varied by iPhone Devices

Tags: ios, autolayout, interface-builder

I am attempting to vary my auto layout constraint by iPhone version. The vary for traits allows you to differ by size classes. However all the iPhones in portrait orientation are all compact width and regular height.

Assuming I have an element that is horizontally centered but I want my distance from the top of my main view to vary based upon device size, how should I accomplish this?

Comment: You mean in some way more complicated than being proportional to the size of the superview? Not just e.g. always a third of the way down whatever distance there is?

Comment: @Tommy I mean on an iPhone SE I may want the element 5 from the top, on the larger iPhone 6 15 from the top, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot specify screen-sizes or device versions in auto-layout - only size classes.

If relative positioning/sizing doesn't work for you, and you want to do positioning such as 5 pts on iPhone SE and 15 pts on iPhone 6, you have to do it via code. Your options are:

1. Don't use auto-layout...
2. Change constraint values (constants, multipliers, priorities, etc)

If you read through Apple's docs on auto-layout, you can see it is targeted toward *adaptive* interface design, not *alternate* interface design.

Comment: I agree with this answer; if it adds anything then (2) is very strongly my favourite of the two options as it lets you mix and match. E.g. if all you want is to change the amount of space at the top before a certain element, then for everything underneath to be spaced and sized per normal rules, set the whole thing up with constraints and then tweak just the one value to get a full layout. Otherwise you'll need to implement for yourself even those things that auto layout could be doing for you.

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1 : Programmatically changing Constraint Values**

If you want to set different constant top values for iPhone variation, then create a outlet of Top Constraint and change its constant value.

```
_topConstraint.constant = Conditional code for each device.
```

**Method 2 : Setting Adaptive Constraints**

Eg: I have taken a view with fixed height = 100, width = 200 and centred it horizontally.

[image]

Now it give a proportionate top space as per the device size, please gear up for some maths.

Suppose, the top space in iPhone5 screen = 36 pt.

Total View Height   = view top + view height = 36 + 100 = 136

Total Screen Height = 568 Bottom Ratio = 568/136 = 4.17

So, set a bottom layout constraint and add the multiplier as 4.17. [image][image]
[image][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FdQWw.png)
[image]

On iPhone 7 plus and other devices, it changes the top automatically.